# Pyside and Qt4 returning an empty window

Tags: python-2.7, qt4, desktop-application, pyside, qt-designer

I made an interface using Qt designer and saved it in a file main.ui

So, i've tried 2 ways to show my window using python and both returned an empty window:
[image]

First attempt (using the main.ui directly):

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide import QtUiTools

class MainApp(QMainWindow):
    def init(self, *args):
        apply(QMainWindow.__init__,(self,) + args)

        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        file = QFile("main.ui")
        file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        self.myWidget = loader.load(file, self)
        file.close()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.myWidget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import os
    print "Running in %s.\n" % os.getcwd()

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()

    app.connect(app, SIGNAL("lastWindowClosed()"),
               app, SLOT("quit()")
    )
    app.exec_()
```

For the second attempt, I used Pyside-uic.exe to generate a main.py file:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from qt_gui.main import *
import sys

class MainApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def init(self, parent = None):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've saw a lot of examples doing the same but none worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second method using Pyside-uic should work, but you need to call the `__init__` method correctly (underscores were missing in your example code):

```
class MainApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui

from PyQt4.uic import loadUiType
# This method of the PyQt4.uic module allows for dynamically loading user
# interfaces created by QtDesigner. See the PyQt4 Reference Guide for more
# info.
Ui_Main = \
    loadUiType(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'main.ui'))[0]
class MainApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, info):
        """Setup the Properties dialog."""

        super(MainApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

It works for me. Just replace `Ui_Main` with the name you are using in your `.ui` file.

I'm using `PyQt` here, but i suppose it will works with `PySide` too.

Comment: Doesn't it work with PySide? I thought most of code that works on PyQt could work with PySide doing minimal changes.

Comment: @Vicent. With PySide, the nearest equivalent is `QtUiTools.QUiLoader.load()`, but that creates an instance, rather than a class - which is obviously a lot less flexible, because there's no straightforward way to make a subclass.